# C++ giving change

Tags: c++

Problem is:
I need calculating change program for vending machine. I made an array for numbers of change(10,50,100,500 = 4 change). While debugging, I realized the numbers of change I initialized didn't work properly

Code:

```
class BeverageVendingMachine : VendingMachine {
public:
static int change[4];
virtual void menu(int remain[])
{
    cout<<"[1] Coke ("<<remain[0]<<" left)"<<endl;
    cout<<"[2] Milk ("<<remain[1]<<" left)"<<endl;
    cout<<"Select menu: ";
}

virtual void CalculateChange(int cost, int money)
{
    int Change = money-cost;

    if (Change>0)
    {
        if ((money-500)>=0){
            money-=500;
            change[0]+=1;
        }
        else{
            change[1]+=(money/1000);
            money -=(money/100)*100;
        }
        if ((money-50)>=0){
            money-=50;
            change[2]+=1;
        }
        else{
            change[3]+=(money/10);
            money -=(money/10)*10;
        }
    }
    cout<<"your Change is "<<Change<<endl;


    if ((Change-500)>=0){
        Change-=500;
        change[0]-=1;
    }
    else{
        change[1]-=(Change/1000);
        Change -=(Change/100)*100;
    }
    if ((Change-50)>=0){
        Change-=50;
        change[2]-=1;
    }
    else{
        change[3]-=(Change/10);
        Change -=(Change/10)*10;
    }


}
};
int BeverageVendingMachine::change[4] = {5,5,5,5};
```

Comment: Off topic, but why is the CalculateChange function in the definition for BeverageVendingMachine, rather than in the generic VendingMachine?

Comment: Because I have to make several kinds of vending machines with independent change.  it's hard for me to make better code than that..T.T

Answer (score 0):

of course your code does not work correctly, you are nor considering all cases. Try this:

```
void CalculateChange(int cost, int money)
{
    int Change = money-cost;

    if (Change>0)
    {
        while ((money-500)>=0){
            money-=500;
            change[0]+=1;
        }
        while ((money-100)>=0){
            money-=100;
            change[1]+=1;
        }
        while ((money-50)>=0){
            money-=50;
            change[2]+=1;
        }
        while ((money-10)>=0){
            money-=10;
            change[3]+=1;
        }

    cout<<"your Change is "<<Change<<endl;
        // print out all the values in change array
}
```

I think the code is self explanatory.

Comment: oh totally missed it, thank you so much. If possible, can I ask more with" int BeverageVendingMachine::change[4] = {5,5,5,5};" <this one, is this right thing to initialize?

Comment: I think you want to initialize it to all zeros because you increment the values there when you calculate the change.